# 'Point-along-path' d3 visualization performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, transition

I have gone through the 'point-along-path' d3 visualization through the code: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868. I have noticed that while the point is moving along its path it consumes 7 to 11% of CPU Usage.

Current scenario, I have around 100 paths and on each path, I will have to move points(circles) from sources to destinations. So it consumes more than 90% of the CPU memory as more number of points are moving at the same time.

I have tried as:

```
                   function translateAlong(path) {
                      var l = path.getTotalLength();
                      return function(d, i, a) {
                          return function(t) {
                               var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
                               return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
                          };
                       };
                    }

                    // On each path(100 paths), we are moving circles from source to destination.
                    var movingCircle = mapNode.append('circle')
                        .attr('r', 2)
                        .attr('fill', 'white')

                    movingCircle.transition()
                        .duration(10000)
                        .ease("linear")
                        .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
                        .each("end", function() {
                            this.remove();
                        });
```

So what should be the better way to reduce the CPU usage?
Thanks.

Comment: I want to reduce the CPU usage while the transition of points is happening.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few approaches to this, which vary greatly in potential efficacy.

Ultimately, you are conducting expensive operations every animation frame to calculate each point's new location and to re render it. So, every effort should be made to reduce the cost of those operations.

If frame rate is dropping below 60, it probably means we're nearing CPU capacity. I've used frame rate below to help indicate CPU capacity as it is more easily measured than CPU usage (and probably less invasive).

*I had all sorts of charts and theory for this approach, but once typed it seemed like it should be intuitive and I didn't want to dwell on it.*

Essentially the goal is to maximize how many transitions I can show at 60 frames per second - this way I can scale back the number of transitions and gain CPU capacity.

---

Ok, let's get some transitions running with more than 100 nodes along more than 100 paths at 60 frames per second.

**D3v4**

First, d3v4 likely offers some benefits here. v4 synchronized transitions, which appears to have had the effect of slightly improved times. d3.transition is very effective and low cost in any event, so this isn't the most useful - but upgrading isn't a bad idea.

There are also minor browser specific gains to be had by using different shaped nodes, positioning by transform or by cx,cy etc. I didn't implement any of those because the gains are relatively trivial.

**Canvas**

Second, SVG just can't move fast enough. Manipulating the DOM takes time, additional elements slows down operations and takes up more memory. I realize canvas can be less convenient from a coding perspective but canvas is faster than SVG for this sort of task. Use detached circle elements to represent each node (the same as with the paths), and transition these.

Save more time by drawing two canvases: one to draw once and to hold the paths (if needed) and another to be redrawn each frame showing the points. Save further time by setting the datum of each circle to the length of the path it is on: no need to call path.getTotalLength() each time.

Maybe something like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/68de3216d0318023626569da44e58539)

**Canvas Simplified Lines**

Third, we still have a detached node that has SVG paths so we can use `path.getPointAtLength()` - and this is actually pretty effective. A major point slowing this down though is the use of curved lines. If you can do it, draw straight lines (multiple segments are fine) - the difference is substantial.

As a further bonus, use `context.fillRect()` instead of `context.arc()`

**Pure JS and Canvas**

Lastly, D3 and the detached nodes for each path (so we can use `path.getTotalLength()`) can start to get in the way. If need be leave them behind using typed arrays, context.imageData, and your own formula for positioning nodes on paths. Here's a quick bare bones example ([100 000 nodes](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/4a5757eb86bf00c6f2e2987d0c064410), [500 000 nodes](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/5c642edf12936fed7a65c074f6efc812), [1 000 000 nodes](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/f5f71939166527cdaa1a2e501ec34862) (Chrome is best for this, possible browser limitations. Since the paths now essentially color the entire canvas a solid color I don't show them but the nodes follow them still). These  can transition 700 000 nodes at 10 frames per second on my slow system. Compare those 7 million transition positioning calculations and renderings/second against about 7 thousand transition positioning calculations and renderings/second I got with d3v3 and SVG (three orders of magnitude difference):

[image]

*canvas A is with curved lines (cardinal) and circle markers (link above), canvas B is with straight (multi-segment) lines and square markers.*

As you might imagine, a machine and script that can render 1000 transitioning nodes at 60 frames per second will have a fair bit of extra capacity if only rendering 100 nodes.

If the transition position and rendering calculations are the primary activity and CPU usage is at 100%, then half the nodes should free up roughly half the CPU capacity. In the slowest canvas example above, my machine logged 200 nodes transitioning along cardinal curves at 60 frames per second (it then started to drop off, indicating that CPU capacity was limiting frame rate and consequently usage should be near 100%), with 100 nodes we have a pleasant ~50% CPU usage:

[image]

*Horizontal centerline is 50% CPU usage, transition repeated 6 times*

But the key savings are to be found from dropping complex cardinal curves - if possible use straight lines. The other key savings are from customizing your scripts to be purpose built.

Compare the above with straight lines (multi segment still) and square nodes:

[image]

*Again, horizontal centerline is 50% CPU usage, transition repeated 6 times*

The above is 1000 transitioning nodes on 1000 3 segment paths - more than an order of magnitude better than with curved lines and circular markers.

**Other Options**

These can be combined with methods above.

*Don't animate every point each tick*

If you can't position all nodes each transition tick before the next animation frame you'll be using close to all of your CPU capacity. One option is don't position each node each tick - you don't have to. This is a complex solution - but position one third of circles each tick - each circle still can be positioned 20 frames per second (pretty smooth), but the amount of calculations per frame are 1/3 of what they would be otherwise. For canvas you still have to render each node - but you could skip calculating the position for two thirds of the nodes. For SVG this is a bit easier as  you could modify d3-transition to include an `every()` method that sets how many ticks pass before transition values are re-calculated (so that one third are transitioned each tick).

*Caching*

Depending on circumstance, caching is also not a bad idea - but the front-ending of all calculations (or loading of data) may lead to unnecessary delays in the commencement of animation  - or slowness on first run. This approach did lead to positive outcomes for me, but is discussed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291755/7106086) so I won't go into it here.

Comment: Nice answer. I have found a 50% speed increase (on my machine) in the Canvas+JS code. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: I had serious performance issues with getTotalLength() in my project and your tip with drawing curves using straight lines was the solution. Enormous performance boost! Especially on mobile. Thanks!

Comment: Using something like d3's transition, you only have access to an eased time in [0,1]. Is there a way to turn this into a tick number so that you can selectively update elements only on certain ticks?

Answer (score 5):

> **Post edit:**
>
> - [Here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/65ecb6e98b36b97051e1c91e076ad426/raw/fdd11e16fd27c2ef4ac7efbf8236469ceee8ad87/defPointAlongPath_many.html) is the default. (peak CPU around %99 for 100 points at 2.7Ghz i7)
> - [Here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/2915f7a33d806c1aaa1e024574e47c5f/raw/44cb955f7326321a25db7a8a9157dec276be1b40/defPointAlongPath_fast_many.html) is my version. (peak CPU around 20% for 100 points at 2.7Ghz i7)
>
> On average I am 5 times faster.

I presume the bottleneck here is the call to `getPointAtLength` method at every 17ms. I would also avoid lengthy string concatenations if I have to, but in your case its not much long so I think the best way:

- cache points beforehand and only calculate once with a given resolution (I divided here in 1000 parts)
- reduce calls to DOM methods within the requestAnimationFrame (that function you see receiving the normalized t parameter)

In the default case there is 2 calls, 1 when you call `getPointAtLength`, and then another one when you are setting the translate(under the hood).

You can replace the `translateAlong` with this below:

```
 function translateAlong(path){
    var points  = path.__points || collectPoints(path);
    return function (d,i){
        var transformObj = this.transform.baseVal[0];
        return function(t){
            var index = t * 1000 | 0,
                point = points[index];
            transformObj.setTranslate(point[0],point[1]);
        }
    }
}
function collectPoints(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength(),
        step = l*1e-3,
        points = [];
    for(var i = 0,p;i<=1000;++i){
        p = path.getPointAtLength(i*step);
        points.push([p.x,p.y]);
    }
    return path.__points = points;
}
```

And a small modification to that tweening line:

```
.tween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
```

setting attr is not necessary, calling it is enough. Here is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/8kx04y29/

Tell me if it did improve, because I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I get an instant -1, after 10 seconds (literally even earlier) of posting. Although it is a working solution, at least from my observations (iOS)

Comment: Thanks @Ibrahim for the optimised solution, this decreases to 30% of my CPU usage.

Comment: There is one issue coming in your solution in "Internet Explorer". Point is not moving along the path because "transformObj" becomes undefined, so it gives error as "Unable to get property 'setTranslate' of undefined or null reference". Otherwise it works fine in other browsers. Can you please help in that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving this might be to use an [svg:animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion) which you can use to move an element along a given path. Here is an example from the [docs](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/). In essence you want:

```
<svg>
  <path id="path1" d="...">
    <circle cx="" cy="" r="10" fill="red">
      <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="0">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path1" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </path>
</svg>
```

I've not profiled it, but I think you're struggle to get much better performance than using something built into SVG itself.

**Browser Support**

Note that after a comment from @ibrahimtanyalcin I started checking browser compatibility. Turns out that this isn't supported in IE or Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Whomever downvoted - it would be nice to explain the reason for the downvote in the comments so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Ian, believe me I feel the same way. I like this solution coz of the simplicity. I'll upvote it to balance, however I heard that google was planning to depreciate SMIL, is it true??

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin Honestly I think you know more about it than me. But according to https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM%5B126-150%5D they seemed to change their mind. That being said I'm not sure on IE/Edge compatibility so I'm going to update my answer to reflect that. Thanks for the upvote - I'd already done yours as being a good code answer :)

Comment: Thank you ian. I think for edge it might be possible port SMIL behavior using CSS keyframes with motion-offset property. I didn't try it but I heard someone did it. Then CPU usage would not be an issue from thereover.

Answer (score -1):

On my computer:

- @mbostock uses 8% CPU.
- @ibrahimtanyalcin uses 11% CPU.
- @Ian uses 10% CPU.

For @mbostock and @ibrahimtanyalcin this means the `transition` and the `transform` update use the CPU.

If I put 100 of these animations in 1 SVG I get

- @mbostock uses 50% CPU. (1 core full)
- @Ian uses 40% CPU.

All animations look smooth.

One possibility is to add a sleep in the `transform` update function using https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/9938317

**Edit**

In the nice [Andrew Reid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340261/9938317) i have found a few optimizations.

I have written a version of the Canvas+JS 100 000 test that only does the calculation part and counts how many iterations can be do in 4000ms. Half the time `order=false` as `t` controls it.

I have written my own random generator to be sure that I get the same random numbers each time I run the modified code.

The blocks version of the code: **200 iterations**

According to the docs for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> parseInt should not be used as a substitute for `Math.floor()`

Converting a number to a string and then parsing the string up to the `.` sounds not very efficient.

Replacing `parseInt()` with `Math.floor()`: 218 iterations

I also found a line that has no function and looks not important

```
let p = new Int16Array(2);
```

It is inside the inner while loop.

Replacing this line with

```
let p;
```

gives **300 iterations**.

Using these modifications the code can handle more points with a frame rate of 60 Hz.

I tried a few other things but they turn out to be slower.

I was surprised that if I pre-calculate the lengths of the segments and simplify the calculation of `segment` to a mere array lookup it is slower than doing the 4 array lookups and a couple of `Math.pow` and additions and a `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: I got reverse your results + tested them in firefox/ie as well (except @ian, didn't test it). For one  thing, I set a resolution of 1000 equal parts (array size 1000) and handicap myself, although rAF cannot fire more then 60fps, that means 600 or even 500 for the array size would do as well.

Comment: Look https://imgur.com/a/Nf6suOe, for 100 points, it doesn't even compare one is 75% the other is aroun 10-17, you want me to upload a test case?

Comment: Nice - I tried the lookup array as well and was surprised by that myself (I hadn't considered math.floor though for some reason - that's a huge time saver) - and I had seen the abandoned line but only after posting the gist - there were a few revisions.

Comment: @AndrewReid: can the `pre-calculate lengths` result be due to cache misses?

Comment: Not sure - It's been stuck in the back of my mind all day, and my ability to test drops off here, I'm not sure on an approach to test, proxy, or estimate time lost on cache misses. However, I am somewhat confident performance can still be substantially improved on that calculation because of how relatively slow Math.sqrt() is on non-square numbers (it's still amazingly fast, but not compared to when supplied a round number).

Comment: @AndrewReid: testing cache miss can be done with an emulator but that is too much for this case. sqrt is now done by the floating point unit and as far as I know it takes as much cycles as there are bits in the mantisse. Maybe it has a detection that the remainder in the calculation is zero and backs of earlier for nice integer squares.